# Python, SMTP Error, socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, smtp.gmail.com

Tags: python, email, smtp

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('email@gmail.com','password')

msg = 'Hello World'
server.sendmail('email@gmail.com','email@gmail.com',msg)
server.quit()
```

I'm getting a `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` for the first line `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.google.com', 587)`. Trying `stmp.office365.com` seems to go through fine but gmail is not recognized.

Comment: Try to figure if is a temporary failure of your gateway or DNS, you could use ping and telnet tools.  Test gmail.com, smtp.gmail.com, stmp.office365.com and some others. If the issues is only in gmail, check with your network and firewall rules